Standalone spark 3.3.0 java application throws access denied exception when reading from files on mounted drive
I'm using spark 3.3.0 on a standalone cluster, and i have mounted drive from which i need to read some files that comes periodically. As spark application is running as spark user and mounted drive is administrated by someone other team, they set up group in which they added spark user and he has these privileges
drwxrwx--- 300  4BANK input

where 300 is owner and 4BANK is group.
Through cmdline as spark user i can access the files in input folder, but when I run my java app and try to access that file i get
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/ftpnis/FM/input

I've added in my app logging for who is current user, which groups he is in, and i get this output
10:42:03 INFO  javaconnect.spooldir.domain.FileProcessor: Owner: 300

10:42:03 INFO  javaconnect.spooldir.domain.FileProcessor: Group: 4BANK

10:42:03 INFO  javaconnect.spooldir.domain.FileProcessor: Permissions: [OWNER_READ, GROUP_EXECUTE, OWNER_WRITE, GROUP_WRITE, GROUP_READ, OWNER_EXECUTE]

10:42:03 INFO  javaconnect.spooldir.domain.FileProcessor: The file is not readable.

10:42:03 INFO  javaconnect.spooldir.domain.FileProcessor: The file is not writable.

10:42:03 INFO  javaconnect.spooldir.domain.FileProcessor: Current User: spark

10:42:03 INFO  javaconnect.spooldir.domain.FileProcessor: Groups: spark 4BANK gbdcs gbdpmx

It seems that spark app is watching the last 3 privileges (for other users).
I don't have any idea why spark user cannot access that file.
I've also tried running as same app on client mode (with other user that isn't spark but has the same privileges), and then I can access it, but for some reason on cluster I cannot.
Did anyone have a similar problem or know how to fix it?

Could it be SELinux denying access rights? Check the usual places: How to read and correct SELinux denial messages

@DavidTonhofer my sys admin says it is disabled sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

There is also systemd sandboxing maybe?

And for more reaching, the Java Security Manager (which, while being scheduled for removal, may still play a role)

@DavidTonhofer sysadmin says that sandboxing isn't problem. And for Java Security Manager, did you mean to implement it to the app?

No, just to make sure it doesn't anything.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
